# Userscript performance when tab loses focus

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, userscripts

I've noticed that when the window is not in focus, the userscript gets a lot slower (About half of the speed, according to a few quick tests that I did). I believe this is Google Chrome's fault and not the script, but is there any kind of solution to that? Any way of keeping the tab in full speed without having to look at it?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome increases the interval value of setInterval calls to 1 second, for tabs that are not active.

https://codereview.chromium.org/6577021

If your code is using setIntervals, you can use the following fix to speed them up when the tab is not active:

[How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome)